# Erratic mouse wheel after upgrade to 12.04

Tags: lubuntu, mouse-wheel

I upgraded from Lubuntu 11.10 to Lubuntu 12.04 (runs on Vmware server). After upgrade, my mouse wheel control don't work as it should. It works in Windows and when I go to Vmware Remote Console to Lubuntu it works also until I use wheel. 
I can go down, but I can't go up with wheel (navigation bar jumps erratically).

Any idea, what is changed?

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer what has changed, but I noticed a few things since I installed Ubuntu 12.04 yesterday:

- The wheel works correctly in Firefox, but doesn't while browsing files and folders (Nautilus) or editing text in gedit.
- If you first place the mouse on top of the scroll bar and then use the wheel, it works fine, even in gedit and Nautilus.

Comment: I tried, but problem exists in all apps with scroll bar ... it works for down, but when I move up, it jumps down and up ...